# WebRTC/getUserMedia - Getting source of stream

Tags: security, webrtc, getusermedia

I have searched far and wide for the answer to this and am surprised that there aren't more people talking about this.

There doesn't appear to be a way to ensure that the stream/track that is selected is a native camera versus a stream provided by something like ManyCam (https://manycam.com/?__c=1) or AlterCam.  The use case for this is secure apps that, for security reasons, want to ensure that the video/images/data coming through the stream comes from a "legitimate" (native camera) source rather than a source that can really be anything and/or altered before it gets to the client code.

Is there any known way of ensuring this?   I'm not looking for a whitelist/blacklist option, since many of the camera programs allow changing of the camera name, which ends up showing up in the label property.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? What code do you expect to implement this into that could be built off of?

Comment: People can install anything they want, including any browser they want. There's no DRM for cameras AFAIK. You'd need to lock down the client before any surface like this would have any meaningful security properties. Try asking on https://security.stackexchange.com/ for more details.